# Column update from one Table to another based on a ID match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in the same database with names table1 and table2. What I need is I have to copy selected columns from table1 and update those columns in table2 based on the ID match. What I have done is :

```
      $sql = " UPDATE table2, table1 SET table2.column1= table1.column1
            where table1.primarykey= table2.primarykey && primarykey= 1 ";
```

This query is not throwing any error but its not updating .I am a pure beginner in mysql field. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Please post `CREATE TABLE` statements (and sample data if applicable).

Answer (score 1):

Your query has an error.  The second `primarykey` reference needs a table alias; otherwise, it is ambiguous.

I would suggest writing the query using explicit `join` syntax:

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN
       table1
       ON  table1.primarykey = table2.primarykey 
    SET table2.column1 = table1.column1
    WHERE table1.primarykey = 1 ;
```

Because you did not catch this error.  I would also suggest checking for errors when you run a SQL statement at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sql_query = UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t1.field1 = t2.field1, t1.field2 = t2.field2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

slight modification with subquery:

```
$sql = " UPDATE table2 SET table2.column1= ( SELECT table1.column1 from table1
        where table1.primarykey= table2.primarykey && primarykey= 1 )";
```